# Best practice with nested components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 nested components:

```
class Component1 extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            person: {
                name: "Genaro",
                age: 125
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SubComponent
                person={this.state.person}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I want It to render `SubComponent` when my parent class' state changes. This is done automatically by React, but I can do it in two ways:

**Option 1 (with state):**

```
class SubComponent extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            person: props.person
        };
    }

    componetWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({ person: props.person });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Name: {this.state.person.name}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

**Option 2 (with instance variables):**

```
class SubComponente extends React {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.person = props.person;
    }

    componetWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.person = props.person;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Name: {this.person.name}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

I only can use a class (I need to call a lot of instance methods). That's why **I can't do this** (the cleaner way):

```
function SubComponent(props) {
    return (
        <h1>Name: {props.person.name}</h1> 
    );
}
```

Both of them work, but:

1. Which is better? In terms of performance, maintainability, etc
2. Is my two options a bad practice? How could I handle this kind of problem in a better way?

I couldn't find an example in this context.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: You don't need to do anything in `SubComponent` actually. When parent's state changes and it rerenders your `SubComponent` rerenders automatically since its prop changes.

Comment: Both are bad. If you don't need to change value of `person` in subcomponent, then don't save it to state (or instance variable, which is weird by itself). Just use it as `this.props.person` in render function, no proxies are needed. Avoid synchronizing props and state unless you really need it, because it's a common source of bugs.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps has been recently considered an UNSAFE method in latest React release. Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I tried to explain in my comment, you don't need to do anything to render your `Subcomponent`. A child component rerenders if its props change via the parent component. So, do not set its props to a state, instead use props directly.

```js
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      person: {
        name: "Genaro",
        age: 125
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { target } = e;
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      person: { ...prevState.person, name: target.value }
    }) )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <p>Change name</p>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <SubComponent
          person={this.state.person}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SubComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Name: {this.props.person.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's why I love Stack Overflow, stupid of me that I never realised in use props directly! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. No, stupidity at all! Just a little bit lack of information. I suggest following the official documentation first. It explains the basic stuff very well.